# How do I tell ColdFusion 9.0.1 to use a directory besides /tmp?

Tags: coldfusion

I installed ColdFusion 9.0.0 today and I'm trying to upgrade to 9.0.1.

- Linux 64bit environment.
- I don't have root access.
- /tmp doesn't seem to have enough room to install 9.0.1

I found the following errors in /opt/coldfusion9/Adobe_ColdFusion_9.0.1_InstallLog.log

```
Install File:             /tmp/515453.tmp/cf-multi-startup
                          Status: ERROR
                          Additional Notes: ERROR - ZeroGlq: No space left on device

Install File:             /tmp/515453.tmp/cf-init.sh
                          Status: ERROR
                          Additional Notes: ERROR - ZeroGlq: No space left on device
```

I tried -D IATEMPDIR=/opt/temp, but installer says it's trying to use /home/coldfusion due to lack of space in /tmp. It tries to use /tmp anyway.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question should be posted on ServerFault.com

Comment: It's a bit of a bugger to move questions between StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my final script that worked. I had to fill /tmp and /home to 100% to get a decent error response out of the bin file. I'm sure my Linux admins were very pleased.

```
cd /opt/coldfusion9/bin
IATEMPDIR=/home/coldfusion
export IATEMPDIR
LAX_DEBUG=1
export LAX_DEBUG
./ColdFusion_update_901_WWEJ_linux64.bin
```